# Problems with click function in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

When I add a comment, and hit the click-able text "Edit" the alert box doesn't pop up. First when I add the second comment, I'm able to hit the "edit" on the first one comment, and the alert box pop up.

[image]

Why that??

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/6/)

```
function addComment(name1) {

    var container = $('#divComments');
    var inputs = container.find('label');
    var id = inputs.length + 1;

    var div = $('<div />', {
        class: 'CommentStyle'
    });

    $('<label />', {
        id: 'comment' + id,
        text: name1
    }).appendTo(div);

    var d = new Date();
    var $fulaDate = $('<div class="floatleft">' + d.getFullYear() + "-" + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + "-" + d.getDate() + "T" + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + '</div>').appendTo(div);

    var $edit = $('<p />', { class: 'edit', text: 'Edit' }).addClass('edit').appendTo(div);

    $('.edit').click(function () {
        alert('Hallo');

    });

    div.appendTo(container);

}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/7/, instead of binding event to `$('.edit')` you need to bind event with `$edit`

Comment: I'll explain what you did wrong in the above code - there are suitable code fixes below.  You create `$edit` and then create an event handler for all elements with the class `.edit`.  *Then* you add `$edit` to the page.  That element is not on the page when you create the event handler, so it doesn't get attached.  Then when you run the function again it attaches itself to the edit elements on the page, which is now the first one, but the 2nd one doesn't yet exist, and so on and so on.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically created elements:

```
$('#divComments').on('click','.edit',function () {
    alert('Hallo');
});
```

---

Also, as suggested by @Archer, you need to move the click handler outside of your function to avoid nested click events from firing multiple times.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/9/)**

Comment: This will fix the problem and is a better way to do it then the OP was going for, but please explain in this answer that he only needs to do this once, outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your implementation is that when you are attaching event like

```
var $edit = $('<p />', { class: 'edit', text: 'Edit' }).addClass('edit').appendTo(div);
$('.edit').click(function () {
    alert('Hallo');
});
```

Edit element which you created just now is not added to DOM *it is appeded to div only, which is not added to DOM*. thus in short it doesn't exists in DOM, thus event is not binded with the button.

So to fix the issue instead of binding event to `$('.edit')` you need to bind event with `$edit`.

```
var $edit = $('<p />', { class: 'edit', text: 'Edit' }).appendTo(div);
$edit.click(function () {
    alert('Hallo');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9jsjw/7/)

However I would recommend you to use **[Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** as

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

*Code*

```
function addComment(name1) {
}
$('#divComments').on('click', '.edit', function () {
    alert('Hallo');
});
```

[**DEMO with event delegation**](http://jsfiddle.net/GbNS3/1/)

Comment: Definitely, event delegation is the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Archer, Agree that's exactly what I have mentioned in the answer, but OP also needs to know what he did incorrect.

Comment: You've not explained what he did wrong, or why event delegation is better in this case.  No-one bothers explaining things on this site.  They're just point-hungry and don't care about the community.  Sad.